# Django q update an already scheduled task

Tags: python, django, schedule, django-q

I am using [Django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to schedule a task at a specified date in an object (lets call this bell). I am successfully able to do so using

```
schedule_obj = schedule(func_name, arg1, arg2, arg3,
                        schedule_type=Schedule.ONCE,
                        next_run=bell.date)
```

when there is an update to the obj bell that holds the date, I want to modify this schedule obj with the updated date (bell.date). Is there a way to check if there is a schedule pending for this specific func_name with the args and then access it to modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving this here since I couldn't find it in the docs but you can access and modify a created django-q Schedule just like any other Django model.

As long as you update the `next_run` and the schedule parameters for the type of schedule you're using, the cluster workers will use the updated info to run:

```py
from django_q.models import Schedule

existing_schedules = Schedule.objects.filter(func=func_name, args=args)

for schedule in existing_schedules:
    schedule.next_run = bell.date
    schedule.save()
```